# JPanel subclass with gridLayout in Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, subclass, paintcomponent

I have subclass(MyPanel) of JPanel that I'm using to draw lines between buttons. Drawing the line works but the problem is that when I'm using MyPanel instead of JPanel the gridLayout doesn't work. What I want from the gridLayout is the spacing between buttons and the choice of how they should be arranged. I've managed to position them in a grid without the gridLayout but I can't get the spacing to work. So what I need help with is either to get he gridLayout to work or a way to fix the spacing between the buttons without the gridLayout. The buttons I have are all added to the gameBoardPanel.

Edit: This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

What I want is to increase the spacing between the buttons with 25 pixels or so.

```
    class MyPanel extends JPanel {//The subclass
    public MyPanel(GridLayout gridLayout) {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));              
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(!drawline)  
            super.paintComponent(g);        

        else{
             g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
             g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(c,c,c2,d2));                  
        }
    }
```

This is the panel that the buttons are added too.

```
    gameBoardPanel=new MyPanel(new GridLayout(yAxis,xAxis,25,25));//creation of a panel        using MyPanel
```

Comment: can you give a visual representation of what you wish to accomplish, and what you're currently getting

Comment: Sure, give me a minute

Comment: And you want the lines drawn between the the circles?

Comment: Correct, the drawing of the lines works, so ignore the else-statement, it contains some code I just tested.

Comment: So these are 25 buttons that you just want space in between? Is that your problem?

Comment: Your conditional invocation of `super.paintComponent` is almost certainly part of the problem, if not the entire problem.  You *must* call `super.paintComponent` before doing anything else in your paintComponent override.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks) and the [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) tutorial.

Comment: @user3124320 you overrode getPreferredSize and this is correct, use getHeight/Weight, then the JPanel to returns proper coordinated in pixels (many times here search by using tag paintComponent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem using the GridLayout with gaps. I'm not sure where your problem is occurring , but here's an example. I'm using layout of 5,5 with 25 gaps.

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyPanel extends JPanel{

    public MyPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 25, 25));
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            add(new JButton(" "));
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new MyPanel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I used the same GridLayout you attempted to use. So I'm not really seeing where the problem is

[image]

Comment: It was this line: setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5, 25, 25)); that fixed it. Thanks pal!